# 'which' command not working in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I am installing a MATLAB toolbox which looks for a file by calling

```
which
```

When I type

```
which filename
```

in the bash, I get

```
/usr/local/bin/filename.
```

But

```
which('filename')
```

in MATLAB command window says

```
'filename' not found.
```

I can see the binary file is there in

```
/usr/local/bin.
```

Also,

```
/usr/local/bin
```

is added to the MATLAB search path, so I am not sure what is going on here. Any suggestions??

Thanks!!
Ayesha

Answer (score 1):

bash `which` only locates executables in Linux path. MATLAB `which` command only locates MATLAB files (`*.m`, `*.p` and MDL files, according to [MATLAB documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/which.html) of `which` command). MATLAB `which` does not locate other binaries. In most cases a file could be located by using both bash `which` and MATLAB `which` if it was named with `*.m` or `*.p` and its directory is in both Linux path and MATLAB path.

I assume that you have `filename` in `/usr/local/bin/`, but not `filename.m`. The problem can also be that the path of your `filename.m` is not in your MATLAB path. Use `path` command to check and modify your MATLAB path, or using menu: File -> Set Path.

So, if `which` command is used in some MATLAB toolbox's install script or install function (MATLAB program), then it is looking for a MATLAB program file `filename.m` or `filename.p`, not for regular Linux binary file `filename`.

Comment: Hmm .. I checked, the /usr/local/bin is there in the list of folders in the path. One thing though, its not a .m file. It's an executable.Is that the problem? I see the installation file for the toolbox is an mfile which calls 'which; and upon not finding it, gives me an error.

Comment: MATLAB `which` locates only MATLAB program files, not Linux executables, unless you name them `*.m` or `*.p`. If `which('filename')` command is used in an install script or function (a MATLAB `.m` file) of a MATLAB toolbox, then it is looking for a MATLAB program file `filename.m` or protected program file `filename.p`, not for Linux executable `filename`.

Answer (score 1):

You might use exist instead of which here. If the file is there, exist will return the code 2.

However, which does work. For example, a .pdf file in my search path:

```
>> which('Fritsch FN - Monontone piecewise cubic interpolation')
'Fritsch FN - Monontone piecewise cubic interpolation' not found.
```

See that which fails to find it, but when I provide the full name, including extension, which works properly.

```
>> which('Fritsch FN - Monontone piecewise cubic interpolation.pdf')
/Users/woodchips/Desktop/Fritsch FN - Monontone piecewise cubic interpolation.pdf
```

Of course, exist works too.

```
>> exist('Fritsch FN - Monontone piecewise cubic interpolation.pdf','file')
ans =
     2
```

My guess is, your problem arises because you failed to include the extension. Which apparently looks automatically for .m, .p, and .mdl files according to the doc.

Comment: hmm .. exist gives ans as 2 (it's an executable so I am not sure what to put it's extension). Anyway, a workaround I found was to use this:   !filename in the command window of MATLAB launches the executable. Not a pretty solution, but works right now.

Comment: To execute programs, instead of `!` you can also use `unix` command.